How can I execute code before simulation run
I'd like to execute some functions e.g. calculate_tdt_minus_4(); to modify my database table before the simulation run.

function calculate_tdt_minus_4():
List <Date> x=selectFrom(arrivals)
    .list(arrivals.tdt);
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
for(Date t : x){
    cal.setTime(t);
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -4);
    
    update(arrivals).where(arrivals.tdt.eq(t))
        .set(arrivals.tdt_minus_4, cal.getTime())
        .execute();
}

I'm aware that in the "Simulation Experiment" section there is a window "Before simulation run". If I insert the function calculate_tdt_minus_4(); I get the following error:

Description: The method calculate_tdt_minus_4() is undefined for the type Simulation.
Location: Optimization_LSZH/Simulation - Simulation Experiment
What I'm doing wrong?

The function is still on Main so your sim experiment does not know about it. 2 options:

move the function itself to the experiment (better if you dont need it during model execution)
use root.calculate_tdt_minus_4(). In the "before sim exp", you have access to your model root which is typically Main. (assumes the func sits on Main)

Also, start learning about the magic lightbulb and those keywords: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/magic-lightbulb
